# Notify my users automatically using firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I designed movie program that let user to select specific movies to let him follow any new news about it. For any important article i notify my user using firebase notification but how to make it automation to notify any one of them about any specific movie or category ?

according to my googling i can do that using google app engine but i am not sure !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple routes to go about what you are looking for. All of them will require you to set up a server, either on app engine or something similar, that continuously updates your database with new information. I would not rely on just data change events on your database in your app to do notifications though. I would look into `Firebase Cloud Functions` as well as `Firebase Cloud Messaging` where you wait for something in the database to change with a function, which then pushes the notifications with cloud messaging.